# Passing values of a data frame column values using for loop\iterate the loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have dataframe where  a variable ProblemArea contains values ("Screen, Modem, LTE, Audio, video"). I used `for` loop to iterate the values and print according to the Problem Area and Print all the records of the dataframe. I tried the code below:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandasql import sqldf
crConcat = ''
ProblemArea = ["Screen", "Modem","LTE", "Audio", "video"]
for x in ProblemArea:
    connComp=pyodbc.connect("DSN=sfdc_qct_mirror;autocommit=true")
    #ODS connection string
    server = 'ODSDB'
    db = 'ODS'
    conn = pyodbc.connect()
    SfDf = pd.DataFrame(columns=['casenumber','createddate','RELATED_CRS__C'])
    query_EffQIPL = ("select distinct CASENUMBER, c.CREATEDDATE ,ch.CREATEDDATE as EditDate, c.CLOSEDDATE,PROBLEM_CODE_1__C   where PROBLEM_CODE_1__C = "+ "'"+ x +"'"+  " and OWNER_LOCATION__C = "+ "'Hyderabad'  " )
   EffQIPL_df = pd.read_sql(query_EffQIPL,connComp)
   EffQIPL_df
```

I got output as the PROBLEMArea "video" cases only, which is last value of loop.

```
CASENUMBER      PROBLEMArea CR_RELATED_TO_THIS_CASE__C
03860369        Video                  No
03867276        Video                  No
04181458        Video                  Yes
03978455        Video                  Yes
04089497        Video                  No
```

But I expect the output of all PROBLEMAreas should be print as:

```
CASENUMBER      PROBLEMArea CR_RELATED_TO_THIS_CASE__C
03860369        Video                  No
03867276        Video                  No
04181458        Video                  Yes
03978455        Video                  Yes
04089497        Video                  No
CASENUMBER      PROBLEMArea CR_RELATED_TO_THIS_CASE__C
09366546        LTE                    NO
98487348        LTE                    YES
CASENUMBER      PROBLEMArea CR_RELATED_TO_THIS_CASE__C
74627267        Screen                 NO
98273476        Screen                 YES
82373498        Screen                 YES
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you're not saving the variable of your for loop to a list or dict, so your overwriting it each time,

try this : (also cleaning your code a little no need for your connection string within the for loop)

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandasql import sqldf
crConcat = ''
ProblemArea = ["Screen", "Modem","LTE", "Audio", "video"]


connComp=pyodbc.connect("DSN=sfdc_qct_mirror;autocommit=true")
ODS connection string
server = 'ODSDB'
db = 'ODS'
conn = pyodbc.connect()
# is this needed?    
# SfDf = pd.DataFrame(columns=['casenumber','createddate','RELATED_CRS__C'])


dfs = []

for x in ProblemArea:

   query_EffQIPL = ("select distinct CASENUMBER, c.CREATEDDATE ,ch.CREATEDDATE as EditDate, c.CLOSEDDATE,PROBLEM_CODE_1__C   where PROBLEM_CODE_1__C = "+ "'"+ x +"'"+  " and OWNER_LOCATION__C = "+ "'Hyderabad'  " )

   dfs.append(pd.read_sql(query_EffQIPL,connComp))

final_ = pd.concat(dfs)
```